# Error in image downloading program in python

Tags: python

**Code**:

```
import urllib.request
import random

def down(url):
    name=random.randrange(1, 100)
    fullname = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullname)
down("https://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/72/MPW-36431")
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/First/one.py", line 8, in <module>
    down("https://www.movieposter.com/posters/archive/main/72/MPW-36431")
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/First/one.py", line 7, in down
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullname)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 187, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Please also use your own time and learn formatting rules. You can access them while making your post.

Comment: You're request is getting blocked by the website. You can see you are getting the `403` response code. Try adding a user-agent, if that doesn't work maybe your ip is blocked or you are accessing a page you don't have permission to access.

Comment: thanks, that solved it